# Run command after entire loop completes in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a loop in Windows command line:

```
FOR %i IN (*.swf) DO swfrender %i -o %~ni.png && "next command"
```

The "next command" executes after every iteration of the loop.  How do I make it so the entire loop finishes, then the "next command" runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without parantheses, the `&&` binds to the command in`do`. Try this instead.

```
(FOR %i IN (*.swf) DO swfrender %i -o %~ni.png) && "next command"
```

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the next command on the next line and put parenthesis around the command in the for loop :

```
FOR %i IN (*.swf) DO (swfrender %i -o %~ni.png)
"next command"
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I press enter to go to the new line, the first line runs.  How to I input both lines then run?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were in a batch file, not directly in a command window. The solution proposed by dxiv should work.